# Is this the correct way of reusing a JS function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a two functions written that works great. One function will add the HTML video attribute `autoplay` to the video DOM element, if the user is at a certain section on the page. Another function will slide in some elements with a nice transition.

But the downside is that it will work for one element within page, but I would like to have it work on other elements as well.

Here is one function, the one that play the video on scroll:

```
playOnScroll: function() {

    var player = $('.browser video');
    var hasReached = false;

    function isInView(elem){
        return $(elem).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).height();
    }

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var section = $('#user-experience');

        // If section exists
        if (section.length) {

            if (isInView(section) && !hasReached) {
                // console.log('play video');
                hasReached = true;
                player.get(0).play();
            }

        }

    });

}
```

For now the function does only the work if the section with the id `#user-experience` is in view, but it would be great if I can use the function for more sections.

At the moment of writing, I am thinking about to change the target section to a classname and if a section has this class it will do its work. Or is there some better way to do this?

If I take a look at my second function that I mentioned before, that will handle some nice incoming animation on scroll, I doesn't know how to reuse this function for multiple element selectors:

```
moduleShift: function() {

    var root = this;
    var el = $('.entry figure');
    var offset = 0.8;

    root.isVisible(el, offset);

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        // Get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowPos = $(this).scrollTop();

        setTimeout(function(){ 
            root.isVisible(el, offset); 
        }, 1000);

    });

}, 

isVisible: function(el, offset) {

    el.each(function() { 
        var elHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var offsetBottom = offsetTop + elHeight;

        if (offsetTop <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()*offset) {
            $(this).addClass('moduleShift');
        };

    });

}
```

The same solution for above should be able to apply also to this function, but maybe the same question as for the first function, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, maybe try passing variables to the functions instead of having the selectors defined inside them?

Comment: Would perhaps make more sense to use a function to check which section currently is in view, and then check if that section contains a video to be autoplayed …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/). It's propably the easiest way to do that. Your functions `isVisible` and `moduleShift` should be handlers for events triggered when user scroll to a certain point. For example:

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('placeOfYourVideoPlayer'),
  handler: moduleShift;
})
```